# php urlencode does not return the same value as w3school ref table

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a small problem...
if I use the php function to convert a utf8 string like `André` the php function url encode('André') returns Andr%C3%A9.

but if I have a look at the w3school ref table, the proper urlencode for é is %E9...

see here: [www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

How can I get the proper url encoded string in php?

Comment: What encoding do you use?

Comment: One more reason for not to believe on references by w3schools

Comment: Maybe it's just different variants of `é`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the encoded reference value on w3schools is in iso-8859-1 encoding, while your version is encoded using utf-8. The example given by vvr02 won't matter, as the encoding presented in the HTML document won't affect the encoding used when saving the file.

Your version, where the file is saved in UTF-8-format, returns the utf-8 representation of é, while vvr02's version which is saved in iso-8859-1 (or similar) returns the iso-8859-1 representation of é.

They're both correct depending on the context.

Comment: thank you very much for this hint! yes my data is stored in a database with utf8 encoded... the problem is that I have to send this data over a web service, and they did not accept my utf8 string so I had to convert it to url encoded string.. if I first use the function utf8_decode() and then urlencode I guet the right string...

Answer (score 0):

Just now i checked it is giving correct repose. This is what it is giving "Andr%E9"

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo urlencode("André");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Andr%E9 isn't any more "correct" than Andr%C3%A9. As people have explained, it's just to do with the document encoding, which can either be set by a meta tag or a HTTP header.